# What is the difference between Active and passive queues?

Tags: network

Hi guys could you please help me. I want to understand the fundementals of Queuing but I am stuck on the difference between Active and passive queues. Firstly, what is an active queue? Secondly, what is a passive queue? Thirdly, what's the difference between the two? And finally, which out of the two would be the most preferable or better type of queue to go with?

I want to know the meanings of active queue and passive queue and the main differences between the two. What does it mean when you configure a network queue to be active or passive?

Any help you do give would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Please give us some context for your question.

Comment: That's not really what I meant. I mean in what context are you seeing active/passive queues that prompts your question. I am not familiar with active/passive in relation to queues.

Comment: You'll need to tell us which device you're referring to. Likely, this active and passive differentiation is vendor-specific.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamentals are pretty simple:

- In **passive queueing** the network device just discards packets if an output queue is full
- In **active queueing** the network device uses algorithms to work out which packets it should drop from its queue

The issue with refuse-latercomers is that it has unexpected consequences of synchronisation of flows and problems such as "congestion collaps".  What kinds of active management a given device has depends on the exact device.

- Good wikipedia summary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_queue_management
- [RFC 7567](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7567) "IETF Recommendations Regarding Active Queue Management"